# Unexpected result from the dot product in cupy

Tags: cupy

The following piece of code produces unexpectedly large result:

```
import cupy as cp, numpy as np

N=500
aa1=cp.random.randn(N,N)
aa2= cp.random.randn(N,N)
aa3=cp.random.randn(N,N)
cc=aa1.dot(aa2).dot(aa3)

cp.dot(aa1,aa2,out=aa2)
cp.dot(aa2,aa3,out=aa2)
print(cp.max(cp.abs(cc-aa2)))

%output: 40070455.39606033
```

Also, when I run it multiple times, it prints different (but always large) numbers. I suppose that the issue is in the `cp.dot` part, so that the `aa2` matrix is not equal to the product of the three original matrices.

Interestingly, when I reduce the problem size from `N=500` to `N=100`, it always prints `0` as I would expect. As far as I understand, there is no issue with concurrent execution and race conditions, since every operation is executed in order by the NULL stream (the default stream waits for all of the instructions to complete before starting the next matrix-matrix multiplication).

Ubuntu 18, GPU Titan RTX, cuda toolkit 11.0, cupy 9.2.0

Comment: `cupy.dot()` doesn't seem to like the output array being one of the input arrays.

Comment: @RobertCrovella This is true, and I did couple of tests that indicate that this is the case: if the output array is different, there is no issue. However, this is not how NumPy behaves (and cupy tries to mimick the NumPy functionality). I am curious whether this is a bug of cupy, or if I misunderstand something

Comment: https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/5450  (Yes, I imagine you filed that issue, this is for convenience of others)

Comment: @RobertCrovella Indeed, I submitted this issue, and there is response confirming that this is a bug that needs to be fixed